# npm pack/publish won't pack .gitignore or .npmrc files

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-pack

I have built a project generator for my company. It's a globally installed npm package, that when run, takes the entire contents of a `/template` directory inside the package and copies it to the user's chosen destination.

Inside `/template` I have 2 files that `npm pack` **refuses to include** in the final published module:

`/template/.gitignore`

`/template/.npmrc`

Everything else, including other hidden files, get packed as expected.

These 2 files are not in any root (or nested) .gitignore files, and I'm not manually specifying any `files` array in any package.json that npm might pick up on.

Comment: Show your JSON code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You must be having a package.json file ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fkvwnQxu

Comment: Same problem. Node copy everything in my project template but .gitignore & .npmrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional behaviour https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

The workaround was to create .gitignore.template and rename on install

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly adding to `files` in `package.json` will force `npm pack` to include the files

```
"files": [
    "dist",
    "dist/template/.npmrc",
    "dist/template/.gitignore"
  ]
```

Comment: or simply use `"files": ["**/*"]`, [ref](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files)